# MCAR tests on mixed variable datasets [findings + discussion]

Tags: r, categorical-data, nonparametric, missing-data, data-imputation

I have been spending a whole week on researching about testing on missingness mechanism in datasets and I thought it will be helpful to share what I found out about the 2 available MCAR test packages in R. Please do not slam me as I am still fairly new to this community, and I'm hoping I can learn a thing or two because I realized that this missingness mechanism diagnosis is still fairly new, so I may or may not be correct:

1. BaylorEdPsych's LittleMCAR

   - works on mixed data
   - but does not work on non-parametric distributions, assumes multivariate normality
   - null hypothesis is that data is MCAR. If p-value < 0.05, reject null hypothesis that data is MCAR. Otherwise there is not enough evidence to reject = possible that data is missing randomly (note that it doesn't give 100% certainty that data is MCAR because its a common mistake highlighted in a few research papers)

2. MissMech's MCARNormalityTest (answer confirmed by one of the authors of MissMech package)

   - works on non-parametric distributions
   - but does not support categorical data (even if you encode it)

If anyone knows of tests of missingness mechanism for mixed variables data (and without predictor variables unfortunately), please bounce off here. Appreciate it